# Question in English but code in a foreign language. Is this according to policy?

Tags: discussion, languages, code

Recently, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838284/c-the-loop-is-somehow-not-ending), which is a English question but the code is obviously not.

I've searched around and found the [official policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) on foreign languages and wondered if this applies?

To be fair, the code is legal (as in it compiles and runs) and there isn't exactly a rule mandating language of code, but I find incomprehensible identifiers very hard to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need to have the code in English per se. However, you should be able to read the code and understand the issue at hand.

What if you would replace all variables with `i`, `n`, `x` or other often used iterator variable names? You can't really say that is 'English', but it isn't helpful either.

So English or not, **as long as you can understand the question**, there is no problem when the variables or methods used are not written in English.